# Count method showing twice

Tags: java, arrays

I need some help trying to fix an error I am getting:

Here is my code:

```
while(inFile.hasNext()){
   String line = inFile.nextLine();
   String[] lineArray = line.split("\\s+");
   list.add(line);
   Arrays.sort(lineArray);
   System.out.println("Total number of elements in array : " + lineArray.length );
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lineArray)+ "\n");
```

Every time I run this, it prints:

```
Total number of elements in array : 120
[1, 100, 102, 108, 121, 124, 124, 124]

Total number of elements in array : 1
[]

Total number of elements in array : 125
[104, 105, 114, 115, 115, 119, 123]

Total number of elements in array : 1
[]

Total number of elements in array : 106
[104, 105, 114, 115, 115, 119, 123, 141, 142]
```

I would like to remove the total number of elements:1 that keeps showing up and remove the "[]" character but I been stuck trying to figure it out for hours. Also my sorting method is not very efficient and will not correctly sort the array. Can you guys give me some hints or ideas? I have a feeling I messed up somewhere and missing it.

Comment: How do you have stored your data in your file?

Comment: All of that logic is inside the same while loop?  You are sorting the array line-by-line each time a new line is read?

Comment: Basically the data file has a few lines of numbers then a new line then another set inside.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to remove the total number of elements:1 that keeps showing up

Easy-peasy, remove this print statement:

> ```
> System.out.println("Total number of elements in array : " + lineArray.length );
> ```
>
> ... and remove the "[]" character

So slice off the beginning and the end of `Arrays.toString`:

```
String s = Arrays.toString(lineArray);
System.out.println(s.substring(1, s.length() - 1));
```

> Also my sorting method is not very efficient

Erm, you're using Java's `Arrays.sort`, so that's efficient, fine like that.

> ... and will not correctly sort the array.

I suppose you mean that the values are not sorted numerically but alphabetically.
To sort them numerically, you'd have to convert `String[]` to a numeric array before calling `Arrays.sort`.

```
String line = inFile.nextLine().trim();
if (!line.isEmpty()) {
    String[] lineArray = line.split("\\s+");
    int[] nums = new int[lineArray.length]
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
        nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(lineArray[i]);
    }
    Arrays.sort(nums);
    // ....
}
```

Comment: If that's all inside the same while loop for not end-of-file, the sort will be called for each line of the file.

Comment: I still need to count the # of elements in the array though! Here is what the sort is doing towards the end:

488, 490, 501, 56, 57, 66, 71, 71, 72, 76, 77, 79, 83, 88, 91

Which is not correctly sorted

Comment: It looks like my sort method only cares about the first two digits not all three, I will have this sort 66, 71, 722, 83, 88, 912

Comment: @AlexMalos see my last update: your sort is alphabetic, and it seems you want numeric. For that you need to convert `String[]` to an appropriate numeric type for your purpose (`int[]` perhaps)

Comment: I got this error now:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""